# Create folders in python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.4

I would like to find out if there is any way of making code to create and open folders in python, I've looked around the web but I can't seem to find anything that's simple and can be implemented into current code. Is there  a way of doing it like making a text file or a different way? If there is, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.mkdir

Comment: Thanks, but how would the code work if the user could decide the name of the folder?